# Pass an object with a filter/group in children list

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have an object

```
public class Parent{
     public List<string> docs
}

Parent p = new Parent();
p.docs.Add("First");
p.docs.Add("Second");
p.docs.Add("Third");
p.docs.Add("Fourth");
p.docs.Add("Fifth");

process(p); //some method which take Parent
```

Can you pass in object `p` to `process` method by only having one/group of child and call it for every group of children. I am finding a little bit hard to explain, but below is essentially what i want to do

`process(p); Parent` -> children `First,Second` 
`process(p); Parent` -> children `Third, Fourth` 
 `process(p); Parent` -> children `Fifth`

Comment: I just want pass an object A which has a list member B(which has 20 objects inside) inside it. I would like to pass the object A to a method by only having 5 items in the list member B. Hope I put in right words now,.

Comment: Sure, that is the problem, `p` is not a list, `docs` inside `p` is a list. But i need to pass `p` with `docs` having only 5 items in it

Comment: Yes Sir, I want to pass them in groups of 5.

Comment: There are some other members in it, for which the values should get passed in as is for every list group, only the list should be sent in groups.

Comment: If I do that, there is lot of other code which needs to be tested and other dependencies. I will have to if there is no choice, but was wondering if there is a way to do the above.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try something Like this

```
public class Parent{
     public List<string> docs
}

Parent p = new Parent();
p.docs.Add("First");
p.docs.Add("Second");
p.docs.Add("Third");
p.docs.Add("Fourth");
p.docs.Add("Fifth");

process(new Parent{docs =p.docs.Take(5)});


before that i would recomend you to check memberwiseclone (Shallow Copy,Deep Copy)
```

Comment: Edit your post to change "Taske" in "Take".